# How can I remove nodes from a SiteMapNodeCollection?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, repeater, sitemap

I've got a Repeater that lists all the `web.sitemap` child pages on an ASP.NET page.  Its `DataSource` is a `SiteMapNodeCollection`.  But, I don't want my registration form page to show up there.

```
Dim Children As SiteMapNodeCollection = SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes

'remove registration page from collection
For Each n As SiteMapNode In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes
If n.Url = "/Registration.aspx" Then
    Children.Remove(n)
End If
Next

RepeaterSubordinatePages.DataSource = Children
```

The `SiteMapNodeCollection.Remove()` method throws a

> NotSupportedException: "Collection is read-only".

How can I remove the node from the collection before DataBinding the Repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shouldn't need CType

```
Dim children = _
    From n In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes.Cast(Of SiteMapNode)() _
    Where n.Url <> "/Registration.aspx" _
    Select n
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq and .Net 3.5:

```
//this will now be an enumeration, rather than a read only collection
Dim children = SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes.Where( _
    Function (x) x.Url <> "/Registration.aspx" )

RepeaterSubordinatePages.DataSource = children
```

Without Linq, but using .Net 2:

```
Function IsShown( n as SiteMapNode ) as Boolean
    Return n.Url <> "/Registration.aspx"
End Function

...

//get a generic list
Dim children as List(Of SiteMapNode) = _
    New List(Of SiteMapNode) ( SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes )

//use the generic list's FindAll method
RepeaterSubordinatePages.DataSource = children.FindAll( IsShown )
```

Avoid removing items from collections as that's always slow. Unless you're going to be looping through multiple times you're better off filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with code below:

```
Dim children = From n In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes _
               Where CType(n, SiteMapNode).Url <> "/Registration.aspx" _
               Select n
RepeaterSubordinatePages.DataSource = children
```

Is there a better way where I don't have to use the `CType()`?

Also, this sets children to a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)`.  Is there a good way to get back something more strongly typed like a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.SiteMapNode)` or even better a `System.Web.SiteMapNodeCollection`?