# sitemap remove a node

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I have a web.sitemap, for a particular case I need to remove the node  `<siteMapNode url="~/mainv.aspx" title="MainV" description="">`  from it. But I am getting SiteMapNode Collection is read-only exception. Is there a way to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
  <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Home" description="">
    <siteMapNode url="~/main.aspx" title="Main" description="">
      <siteMapNode url="~/mainv.aspx" title="MainV" description="">        
      <siteMapNode url="~/last.aspx" title="Last" description="">
      </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The code

```
protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound(object sender, SiteMapNodeItemEventArgs e)
{
e.Item.SiteMapNode.ReadOnly = false;
e.Item.SiteMapNode.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(2);
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound(object sender, SiteMapNodeItemEventArgs e)
    {

SiteMapNodeCollection modifiableCollection = new SiteMapNodeCollection(e.Item.SiteMapNode.RootNode.ChildNodes);
                        modifiableCollection.RemoveAt(2);
    }
```

Now I'm getting Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index

Comment: Since sitemapcollection is readonly a workaround is to create a new siteMapCollection to bound, that does not contain the undesired entry.

Comment: @Furqan I tried siteMapCollection but i am unable to find the element to delete

Comment: dear create a new SiteCollectionMap object using the existing SiteMapCollection and then bind the newSCMap.can u try this.

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297/how-can-i-remove-nodes-from-a-sitemapnodecollection

Comment: you say _I tried siteMapCollection but i am unable to find the element to delete_, can you put your code that you tried?